# How to mock partial methods with Spy

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito, junit4

I'm making a unit test in my project.

I wrote a test script to test a class with spy and I mock a method with "Mockito.doReturn". But it seems doesn't work on that method which I mocked.

In my test case, I mock the syncLogs() and set a return value to be "false".Therefore, the "syncLogs()" shouldn't be executed and the return value must be "false".

Actually, the syncLogs() which I mocked still was executed and return value is "true". I don't know why mock is not working in my test.

Does anybody have any idea or encounter this problem?

```
class ApplicationTest{

public void testCase2() {
    setArgs(new String[] {"2018-04-23 00:08:00", "2018-04-23 00:10:00", "" });
    String startTime = "2018-04-23 00:08:00";
    String endTime = "2018-04-23 00:10:00";
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
    ApplicationCmdLine spy = Mockito.spy(ApplicationCmdLine.class);

    Mockito.doReturn(false).when(spy).syncLogs(startTime, endTime, message);
    TestCase.assertEquals(true, spy.manualSyncProess(getArgs()));
  }
}

class ApplicationCmdLine {

public boolean manualSyncProess(String[] args){...
   String information;
   if(!syncLog(.....))
      printUsageMessage(information);
}
public void printUsageMessage(StringBuilder message){
   System.out.println(message);
}
public boolean syncLogs(String startTime, String endTime, StringBuilder message) {....}

}
```

Thanks for your helping :)

Comment: Additionally, I had to try "mock" in my test too, but void method"printUsageMessage()" cannot be executed. In my test, I wish syncLog() cannot be executed other methods should be ran, but it's not working in my code.

Comment: in your method flow I do not see if `syncLogs` is called at all from `manualSyncProcess`

Comment: @DhawalKapil thanks your reply

Sorry, I didn't put complete code here. But the process will be manualSyncProcess --> syncLog <Mock>--> printUsageMessage.

why I wnat to mock syncLog(), because this method will do trasaction with database. I just want to test manualSyncProcess is working well